# EU Blue Card Extension

Tags: germany, blue-card

I was recently issued a blue card. Expiry of blue of the card is about one year corresponding to the expiry of my passport.

Though I have a permanent contract, I was told by the immigration officer that they cannot issue a card with an expiry longer than the passport itself.

When applying for the extension of the card, will the new salary threshold will be applied on my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326798/en/ you should be able to extend your blue card after your passport has been extended without the need of qualifying yourself once again.

That said: It would probably help to answer as best as we can, if you provide a little bit more information. Are you working in a field of scarcity with lower sales tresholds? Which field are you working in? Where are you located?

Comment: Are you working in a field of scarcity with lower sales thresholds? Yes, I am working in the field of Information Technology, I am located in the city of Wuppertal.